# Calling save with $resource in angularjs does not pass complex objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having problems passing complex objects down in the save for the $resource.  It's stripping out nested objects.  Angular 1.2.6.

For example, I define a service:

```
services.factory(
    'DocumentService', 
    [
        '$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return  $resource(
                    '/app/rest/document/:id?user=:user', 
                    {
                        id: "@id", 
                        user: "@user"
                    }, 
                    {}
            );
        }
     ]
);
```

I pass in the document service and fetch a document.  It gets set into the scope upon success.

```
DS.get(
    {id : documentId, user: $scope.user},

    function(data) {
        $scope.document = data;
    }
);
```

I add an object signifying that the document has been edited:

```
$scope.document.documentEdit = {
    user : $scope.user,
    editAction : "update"
};
```

and another field:

```
$scope.document.testField = "this goes down";
```

When I call either of the following:

```
$scope.document.$save({id : documentId, user: $scope.user});
DS.save({id : documentId, user: $scope.user}, $scope.document);
```

The "testField" gets serialized and posted, but the "documentEdit" field does not.  Interestingly enough, if I do the following:

```
DS.save({id : documentId, user: $scope.user}, angular.toJson($scope.document));
```

It works; both fields get sent down.

What am I missing?

I stepped though the angular code in angular-resource.js. There's a portion of code:

```
var serverRequest = function(config) {

    headers = config.headers;
    var reqData = transformData(config.data, headersGetter(headers), config.transformRequest);

    // strip content-type if data is undefined
    if (isUndefined(config.data)) {
      forEach(headers, function(value, header) {
        if (lowercase(header) === 'content-type') {
            delete headers[header];
        }
      });
    }

    if (isUndefined(config.withCredentials) && !isUndefined(defaults.withCredentials)) {
      config.withCredentials = defaults.withCredentials;
    }

    // send request
    return sendReq(config, reqData, headers).then(transformResponse, transformResponse);
};

var chain = [serverRequest, undefined];
var promise = $q.when(config);
```

By the time it hits serverRequest the documentEdit has been filtered out.

Comment: if it works when you serialize it into JSON, then what is the problem?

Comment: That feels like a hack, and it's not supposed to work that way to the best of my knowledge.  I haven't seen any other examples where this was needed, so it makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I agree. I would be interested to find an answer to this question too. Have you considered rectangular? https://github.com/mgonto/restangular I think it supports what you want to do.